# Why is CakePHP Form helper grouping my form radio options?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

```
echo $this->Form->create('AmazonMatches', array('action' => 'selectMatches'));
echo $this->Form->input('option_id', array('options' => $allAmazonMatches, 'type' => 'radio'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
```

Now I see a box around my radio buttons with a large red text saying "Option Id".

How can i get rid of it? Sorry I am a total Cake noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the 'legend' option to false if you don't want to show it, or to a string if you want to customize the message:

```
echo $this->Form->input('option_id', array(
    'options' => $allAmazonMatches,
    'type' => 'radio',
    'legend' => false
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Form->input
```

Creates one input field with the `id` provided. You'll have to create multiple inputs inorder to make your checkboxes work separately.
There could be better methods, but doing it something likethis will work.

```
foreach($allAmazonMatches as $amazonMatch)
{
  $this->Form->input...
}
```